# subprocess.call('pyro-ns') sync with threading.Lock

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-multithreading

I want to **start a subprocess** by function subprocess.call(), and i want **the main loop waits until the subprocess has started**.

I thought to **use a threading.Lock**:

- ***acquiring it*** before the the subprocess.call()
- then ***trying to re-acquire it*** (so it waits)
- and ***releasing it after subprocess.call()*** (main loop is unlocked)

**The subprocess has to run as a daemon**, so i put the subprocess.call() inside a thread.

But it stops after the subprocess.call(), i think it's just waiting because pyro-ns is a daemon that listens on a port. How can i do this working?

See the code, it's easier:

```
self.__wait_pyroNS_lock=threading.Lock()
self.__logger.debug('i get wait_pyroNS_lock')
self.__wait_pyroNS_lock.acquire()

pyro_ns = threading.Thread(name='Pyro Name Server', target=self.__Pyro_NameServer, args=(self.__wait_pyroNS_lock,))
pyro_ns.setDaemon(True)

self.__logger.debug('starting thread def self.__Pyro_NameServer')
pyro_ns.start()

self.__wait_pyroNS_lock.acquire() # <--- MAIN LOOP WAITING HERE
self.__wait_pyroNS_lock.release()



def __Pyro_NameServer(self, wait_pyroNS_lock):

    try:
        self.__logger.debug('def __Pyro_NameServer')

        self.__logger.debug('starting pyro-ns')
        retcode = subprocess.call("pyro-ns", shell=True) # <--- THREAD STOPS HERE, it doesn't return, so i don't get any code and it's all locked.

        if retcode != 0:
            self.__logger.debug('command pyro-ns: fail, error code %d' % retcode)
            else:
                self.__logger.debug('pyro-ns has started')

            self.__logger.debug('releasing wait_pyroNS_lock')
            wait_pyroNS_lock.release() # <--- IT NEVER RUNS, it releases the lock, the main loop is unlocked

        except Exception as e:
            self.__logger.error('%s' % str(e))
```

Comment: if you do -1, at least try to explain it, don't be an idiot, you're just ruining the community, thanks

Comment: start demon in background:
`retcode = subprocess.check_call("pyro-ns &", shell=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use the API provided by PyRO.

```
pyro_ns_object = Pyro.naming.NameServerStarter()
pyro_ns = threading.Thread(name='Pyro Name Server', target=self.__Pyro_NameServer, args=(pyro_ns_object,))
pyro_ns.setDaemon(True)
self.__logger.debug('start thread def self.__Pyro_NameServer')
pyro_ns.start()

while True:
    if pyro_ns_object.waitUntilStarted(timeout=0.1):
        break
    else:
        self.__logger.debug('waiting pyro-ns')


def __Pyro_NameServer(self, pyro_ns_object):

    try:
        self.__logger.debug('def __Pyro_NameServer')

        self.__logger.debug('starting pyro-ns')
        pyro_ns_object.start()

    except Exception as e:
        self.__logger.error('%s' % str(e))
        raise e
```